# c - my push function always pushes the most current element onto every value of the stack

Tags: c, push, printf

So for some reason this function appears to be pushing all of the same value onto the stack (or just printing the same value; i suppose it could actually be something to do with the printAll function which i also included.)? The thing is, for the element array (which is an array of integers), printAll appropriately cycles through the values. But anything concerning the charElement array, the printAll function ONLY prints the most recent value for each and every value in the charElements function. Any idea why this is happening?

```
void pushString(Stack *S, char element[])
{        
    /* If the stack is full, we cannot push an element into it as there is no space for it.*/        
    if(S->size == S->capacity)        
    {                
        printf("Stack is Full\n");        
    }        
    else        
    {                
        /* Push an element on the top of it and increase its size by one*/ 
        S->charElements[S->size++] = element;
        S->elements[S->size-1] = '\n'; 
    }        
    return;
}



void printAll(Stack *S)
// NOTE:  Called w/ user input 'f'
// PRE:   Stack S is initialized
// POST:  Print all values from the stack
//    Do NOT alter anything
{

    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i < S->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", i);
        if(S->charElements[i] == "\n")
        {
            printf("%.2f \n", (float)S->elements[i]);   
        }
        else if(S->elements[i] == '\n')
        { 
            printf("%s \n", S->charElements[i]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show the declaration of the `Stack` type.

Answer (score 0):

```
S->charElements[S->size++] = element;
```

merely copies the pointer to the passed-in `char*` `element`.

If you are using the same buffer to read the input and then pass it to the `pushString` function repeatedly, all stack elements end up pointing to the same buffer, and its contents is the last entered value.

You need to copy the contents, using `strdup` or `malloc` and `strcpy`.

```
S->charElements[S->size++] = strdup(element);
```

resp.

```
S->charElements[S->size] = malloc(strlen(element) + 1);
// check for NULL
strcpy(S->charElements[S->size++], element);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is very strange. Elements are represented by `char []` in the push function, but printed using `%f` in `printAll()`. This doesn't make a lot of sense, to me.

Without the declaration of the `Stack` structure, it's hard to follow the code's intentions.